# Curl is not giving response in PHP

Tags: php

I am working on Push Notification in Android. On server side I implement this code:

```
 $apiKey = "";


$registrationIDs = array( "" );


$message = "hello";


$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';


$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),

                );


$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'

                );



$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );


curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );


curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );


$result = curl_exec($ch);



curl_close($ch);

echo $result;
```

I am using Xampp .First time when i run this code browser give fatal error on curl is not define. Then in php.ini file i uncomment the line extension=php.curl.dll and restart the apache server and then again run this code at that time it does not give any error but doesn't echo the result . I am new to server side any help would be appreciated

Comment: well, silly question, did you echo/print the result?

Comment: well it was silly question beacause i did not add echo $result see my edited question. And i am doing echo $result on my side thats why i am asking

Comment: Try var_dump instead of echo. It may return false on failure. `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.`

Comment: @smottt thanks for help . yes its giving me false so what i can do to make result true? Any help?

Comment: You'll need to debug it. Check Venu's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get more info regarding the error, you can use below code.

```
   $responseInfo    = curl_getinfo($ch);
   $header_size    = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE); 
   $responseHeader = substr($result, 0, $header_size);
   $responseBody   = substr($result, $header_size);

    echo 'Header: <br>'. $responseHeader;
    echo 'Body: <br>'. $responseBody;
```

Please check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

```
$responseInfo['http_code'] -> gives the http response code.
```

Or

If you are not sure how to debug, then please use some libraries which would help you.
[ZendService_Google_Gcm](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Google_Gcm)

Quick reference of [gcm response codes](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

You can handle like this
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_Google_Gcm/blob/master/library/ZendService/Google/Gcm/Client.php#L116

Comment: i used your solution but its giving empty header empty body and on var_dump($result); giving bool(failed)

Comment: please see my updated anwser

Comment: $responseInfo['http_code'] giving 0